# Checking if user is coming from a particular fragment in kotlin with Navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have two fragment, MeasurementFragment and AddMeasurementFragment. The user will first pass through the first fragment and click a button and to go the second fragment and then fill a form and come back to the first fragment when a button is pressed. Then the text from the second fragment will get displayed on the first Fragment.

Here is the piece of code I am working with

```
private  val args: MeasurementsFragmentArgs by navArgs()
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        /*Initialize Views*/

        addMeasurementFab = binding.clientMeasurementFragmentAddMeasurementFab
        addMeasurementFab.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.addMeasurementFragment)
        }

        if (args != null) {
            binding.measurementsFragmentTestingTextView.text =
                args.dressMeasurementModel.measurementName
            addMeasurementFab = binding.clientMeasurementFragmentAddMeasurementFab
        }
    }
```

This is the error that i get with that code

```
2021-06-08 17:45:48.958 6894-6894/com.decagonhq.clads E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.decagonhq.clads, PID: 6894
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MeasurementsFragment{b497b26} (7f2ac57b-72b8-4dd0-a3e6-32c78d76e934 tag=f1) has null arguments
```

Please how can i go about checking if the args is null at the first time?

Comment: Do you use safe args for sending data back or the normal arguments?

Comment: I used safe args to send it @Zain

Comment: Can you show the part that you send the fragment data back

Comment: It sounds like you're not using the APIs to [return a result](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result)? Is there a reason you're not using the APIs specifically for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the delegated property `by navArgs` you would have to populate your args manually, like so

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    val args = arguments
    if (args != null) {
        val measurementArgs = MeasurementsFragmentArgs.fromBundle(args)
        // parse measurementArgs
    }
    // rest of function follows
}
```

You could consider using a ViewModel scoped to the activity to hold the data that you want to share between fragments as well.